# Check if a file is scheduled to be deleted

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

In Windows, a program can schedule a file to be deleted when the computer restarts.

Is there a way to know if a file is scheduled to be deleted, short of restarting the computer, and checking if the file is still there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The MoveFileEx() call with the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag moves a file on the next reboot. If the second parameter (the new name) is NULL, the file is deleted. The list of files to be renamed in this way is stored in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

If you wanted to do this in a batch file or at the command line, I'd recommend you to use "reg /query".

Comment: The sysinternal [`pendmoves`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) tool is an easy way to do this from a command prompt too.

Comment: I don't see this registry key on my Windows 10 install. There's a `FileRenameOperations` key, but it is empty even though I have files queued for deletion.